# How do I insert a component within a MAP of other component in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating a MAP to loop through an array of objects and display the data using a `Card` component. But within that MAP I need to insert another component called `Banner` after the second `Card` element from the loop, then continue the Card loop after the Banner. So it will be something like:

```
card[0] - card[1] - banner[0] - card[2] - card[3]
```

**This is my map:**

```js
    { CardData.map((item) => (
     <Card key={item.id} title={item.title} image={item.image} url={item.url} desc={item.desc} />
    ))}
```

**My banner component looks like this:**

```html
    <Banner title="Sample Title" image="../images/sample.jpg" />
```

How would I be able to achieve this?
Any help will be extremely appreciated! Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Do you want the Banner to show up between each 2 cards? or just once after the card[1] ? i mean card-card-banner-card-card-banner and so on?

Comment: no, in this case the banner should show up just once after the second card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally return the banner right before the card only if the index is 2:

```
{
  CardData.map((item, index) => (
    <>
      {index == 2 && <Banner title="Sample Title" image="../images/sample.jpg" />}
      <Card key={item.id} title={item.title} image={item.image} url={item.url} desc={item.desc} />
    </>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Use <React.Fragment key={index}> instead of <> to prevent the child key error. :wink: